# Read and write via FILE stream to raw memory

Tags: c

I write to c raw buffer via  FILE stream 
that I open file like below:

```
 char fileBuf[1024];
 FILE *fp = fopen("nul", "wb");
 setbuf(fp, fileBuf);
 fprintf(fp, "my str");
```

then when I write to file I write to my buffer `fileBuf`

but I need some way to read from `fileBuf` via FILE stream
some like below?

```
 char local[100];
 FILE *f = fopen("nul", "rb");
 setbuf(f, fileBuf);
 fgets(local,sizeof(local),f);
```

(I work on windows and there don't exist memfile)

Comment: What is the *actual* problem you want to solve by reading from memory like it was a file? This seems like an [XY problem](http://xyproblem.info/).

Comment: I'm not sure you understand what `setbuf` is for. What are you trying to do?

Comment: `snprint()` and `asprintf()` can "print" to memory.

Comment: this is an actual problem. I combine two process to one and  their old connection way was via FILE. I want a quick solution to disappear file

Comment: Yes I can to use sprintf etc but I perffer a center solution

Comment: That first example doesn't work at all, what is the `file` argument of `fprintf`? Please post the working code you have.

Answer (score 1):

You use a variable named `local` (don't, by the way, because it is a reserved keyword) but sets the buffer to `fileBuf`:

```
FILE *f = fopen("nul", "rb");
setbuf(f, fileBuf);
fgets(fileBuf, sizeof(fileBuf), f);
```

Comment: this is only a sample I try other name also

Comment: what is not working? what error / undesired output do you get?

Comment: first in answer I need two buffers one that fget read and other one that fread write , second that fget return null